# Assigning Field Expression to a Button in AutoCAD LT 2020

Tags: autocad

I want to assign the following field expression to a button in AutoCAD LT 2020, with it prompting to select an object which will then change the Object ID to the selected object, and produce the field.

```
%<\AcObjProp.16.2 Object(%<\_ObjId 1277806399264>%).Area \f "%lu2%pr2%ps[, Seconds]%ct8[9.799999999999998E-006]">%
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: This is not possible.**

Automating this task would require the use of an API in order to obtain the appropriate Object ID of the selected object (which isn't accessible using standard AutoCAD commands or DIESEL), and therefore could not be achieved using only toolbar macros in AutoCAD LT.

---

If you wanted an existing example of how to automate this task, if you have access to a version of AutoCAD which supports customisation (specifically the LISP API), you might want to consider my [Quick Field](http://lee-mac.com/quickfield.html) utility, which will allow you to define a custom AutoLISP command such as:

```
(defun c:MyArea ( ) (LM:QuickField "Area" "%lu2%pr2%ps[, Seconds]%ct8[9.799999999999998E-006]" 2))
```

This will create a single-line text (DText) object containing a field referencing the area of another selected object, formatted using the formatting code provided.